# How to enable map local to read post data in Charles

Tags: charles-proxy

I'm trying to use map local in Charles and it seems like a great tool.

The problem is that I have identical path+query post requests and they differ only by json post data.

What I need is to intercept a post request, read its data and if data fits my needs, map it with local file.

Is it possible?

I can see in settings that I can only map based on path or query parameters.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to map different Local files for the same identical path and query requests on Charles unfortunately.

But, they are different Methods, you can do it with the Proxyman app.

Tutorial if you like to know how it works: https://proxyman.io/blog/2020/02/Change-HTTP-status-codes-for-UI-testing.html

[image]

Comment: nope, they are the same method. Only json post data is different